# How to find the correlation between continuous and categorical variables in R

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data, pearson-correlation

sorry, I edited my question.

In R, you can use the `cor ()` function to find the correlation using only Pearson and Spearman correlation between Continuous variables.

Which function should I use to get correlation between categorical variable and categorical variable? and Which function should I use to get correlation between categorical variables and Continuous variable

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "*correlation between categorical variables*" and how are you defining correlation in that context? There are ordinal or rank correlation options via Kendall / Spearman, and you can use `table()` to look at concordances between categorical variables. Also, you could use `tapply` or grouped `boxplot`s to look at relative means and distributions of continuous variables within categories. You're going to have to be clearer about what you want specifically.

Comment: @thelatemail / sorry.. I edited my question. thank you for your point.