# Visual correlation between numerical and categorical

Tags: r, correlation

Is it possible to create a visual correlation map wit numerical and categorical variables?

For example with this values:

```
val1 <- rep(c(1:2),5)
val2 <- rep(c('a','b'),5)
val3 <- paste(val1,val2)
val4 <- c(1:10)^2
val5 <- paste('x',val4)
```

Following on the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053431/how-to-find-the-correlation-between-continuous-and-categorical-variables-in-r) I can do see the correlation as a table like:

```
table(val1,val2)
table(val1,val3)
etc...
```

This somehow helps, but I'm looking to produce something like a correlation map.

Also, there is a problem as it works between numeric & categorical and categorical & categorical, but it doesn't work with numeric & numeric, like table(val1,val4).

Does anyone has an example of how to achieve a visual correlation representation for mixed numerical & categorical variables?

Answer (score 1):

Might want to try out the  `ggpairs` function in GGally package. This may not be the exact answer you want (doesn't calculate the correlations) , which may be problematic as far as interpretation goes (see here [enter link description here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119835/correlation-between-a-nominal-iv-and-a-continuous-dv-variable)) .This is more for visualization of the variable relationships. If we put val1,val2 and val5 into a df we can visualize this as (not the only option). If you have a correlation matrix then I'd use `corrplot` from the `corrplot` package :

```
ggpairs(df,mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = val2),upper = list(continuous = "cor", discrete = "box"),lower = list(continuous = "cor", discrete="dot"))
```

Comment: Thanks thisisrg. Impressive visualization. Hard to interpret as you say, but it is a good point to start.